# What is snapshot builds/sources version?

Tags: version-control

What is snapshot builds/sources version?

Comment: Please provide more context. Where did you see this term being used?

Comment: the Java 7 has it:
http://download.java.net/jdk7/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Specific to JDK 7, snapshot releases are for users to download and review while the platform is still being developed.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html

As a general source control (version control) term, a snapshot version indicates a view of the source code taken at a specific time.
This is not necessarily stable or ready for full use and can be changed in the future, *as opposed to* a release version which is stable and should be final.

Comment: Nice reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

That's another name for so-called *daily build* (or *periodic build* or *nightly build*). A script just builds all the sources periodically. This way anyone who is interested in the recent changes can have the almost freshest version every day. A tag is applied to the sources in the repository so that they can be later retrieved to reproduce the build - that forms "a snapshot" of the sources for that build.

Compare this to "official release" - it is carefully planned. Usually a separate branch is created in the repository where only necessary edits are committed. Then after the team decides it is good enough they run the build process, test it thoroughly and publish.