# Does 0.13.4 incorporate changes from 0.13.4-SNAPSHOT in angular ui?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When we download angular ui of now 10/01/2015 from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ , will 0.13.4 include what's in 0.13.4-SNAPSHOT?

I need to know specifically if when we download 0.13.4 today, that it includes what's in 0.13.4-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is snapshot builds/sources version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277297/what-is-snapshot-builds-sources-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discusssed [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4264), this is working as designed.  The `*-is-open` attribute expects an expression value and not a string.

In the future, please do not double/cross post - it makes it very hard for us to track stuff.  Thanks.